# Redirect after my login in my application

Tags: jsf

Good morning, I need your help please:
What happens is that I'm programming in java with jboss server and am using jsf interface (primefaces), my question is because when I authenticate with a login in my application I get redirected to another page and not the one I want.

The url of the login page is:
...login.xhtml

Once my login is correct leads me to the following url:
...javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml

What I wish when my login is correct is to take me to the following url:
...index.xhtml

Besides my web.xml file has the following code:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Also I noticed that when I remove dependencies on the file pom.xml primefaces ok, after loguearme directs me to the correct url:
...index.xhtml

Please kindly help me.

Comment: Post the relevant code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The container managed security will redirect to the last HTTP request which triggered the authentication check. In your case it's apparently the auto-included PrimeFaces JavaScript file. It look like that you've an overly generic URL pattern in your security constraint, such as `/*` or `*.xhtml`, covering not only the JSF pages, but also the CSS/JS/image resources. That `primefaces.js` file is apparently referenced in the login page. So when the login page is opened, the referenced `primefaces.js` file will trigger the authentication check once again and it will remember to use its URL to redirect after successful login.

You'd like to exclude the JSF resources from authentication checks. You could do that by excluding the common URL pattern `/javax.faces.resource/*` via a security constraint *without* an auth constraint:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Allowed resources.</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <!-- No <auth-constraint>! -->
</security-constraint>
```